# Docker: Let containers communicate to each other but don't expose to internet

Tags: docker, docker-compose, security, ports

I was recently shocked to find out that docker writes its own iptables rules and ignores ufw bindings completely. I had blocked all ports using the `ufw deny incoming command` and then selectively allowed only the ports that I wanted to expose.

I have a very simple setup that utilizes a postgresql container and a simple nodejs application. My primary goal is to keep the postgresql container port off the internet but let the node backend accept requests through port 3333. How do I do that?

My current `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```yml
version: "3"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    command: ["redis-server", "/redis.conf"]
    network_mode: host
  database:
    image: "postgres"
    env_file:
      - ./database/database.env
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./database/init-db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always
    network_mode: host

  backend:
    depends_on: [database]
    build: ./server
    volumes:
      - ./files:/var/lib/files
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    restart: always
    network_mode: host

volumes:
  database-data:
```

Comment: typically you put all your boxes inside a private network where they have zero incoming access from the outside world ( internet ) unless specified by your reverse proxy server ( haproxy or nginx ) yet have full access to and from each other ... aws VPC gives you this so does other private network toolings

Answer (score 1):

When you use network_mode host, the [published ports are ignored](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/), which means the ports that are open in the containers will be the same port in the host. Does not matter what you had declared in `ports`

The default behavior is every service in the compose can talk to each other.

> [Links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links) are not required to enable services to communicate - by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name

let's use this simple compose as an example. There is no network defined, docker will create one.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx1:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
  nginx2:
    image: nginx
```

Nginx1 will be reachable through port 8080 on localhost and any other machines in the network.

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.19.10
```

While nginx2 will even have a port on the host.

```
$ docker-compose ps
      Name                     Command               State                  Ports                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
nginx1_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp,:::8080->80/tcp
nginx2_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      80/tcp
```

And they still reach each other by their internal port using the service name

Accessing nginx1 from nginx2

```
$ docker exec -it nginx2_1 curl -I http://nginx1:80
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.19.10
```

Accessing nginx2 from nginx1

```
$ docker exec -it nginx1_1 curl -I http://nginx2:80
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.19.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `network_mode` to `host`, you can simply make use of `links` (new versions uses `networks`) which will make the communication to happen between two containers.

I have updated the `docker-compose.yaml` file and added `links` to connect `database` service (database container) to be accessed from your `backend` service.

In your backend database configuration, you need to use `database` as the db host. (Here `database` is the service name which is defined in the compose.yaml file)

```
version: "3"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    command: ["redis-server", "/redis.conf"]
  database:
    image: "postgres"
    env_file:
      - ./database/database.env
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./database/init-db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    restart: always
  backend:
    depends_on: [database]
    build: ./server
    volumes:
      - ./files:/var/lib/files
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    restart: always
    links:
      - "database"

volumes:
  database-data:
```